# is codenameOne JSONObject.toString creating malformed JSON with quotes around arrays?

Tags: json, codenameone

I'm using CodenameOne's JSONObject class and when I convert to a string, it appears to be adding quotes where they are not required.

Please have a look and let me know if I am using the class correctly.

I create the JSON Object from a HashMap containing ArrayLists and then convert it to string to send:

```
ArrayList categories;
ArrayList modules;
// add some String values to the Array Lists
HashMap<String,Object> activityData = new HashMap<String,Object>;
activityData.put("categories",categories);
activityData.put("modules",modules);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(activityData);
//more unrelated code and then...
String jsonString = json.toString();
```

the problem is that the ArrayList objects in the hashmap are treated as a quoted string so that parsing it on the other end returns Categories and Modules as Strings, not Arrays.

```
{"categories":"[punches, blocks, kicks]","modules":"[white_to_yellow, yellow_to_orange]"}
```

so for example, instead of categories being interpreted as an array with 3 elements "punches", "blocks", "kicks", it is decoded from JSON as a single string:

```
categories = "[punches, blocks, kicks]"
```

so am I using the class incorrectly, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Which JSONObject class are you using?  The one from the [CN1JSON](https://github.com/shannah/CN1JSON) library?

There was a fix for a similar issue in Nov 2015.  Are you using an old version of the lib?

Comment: I have same problem. Using the CN! library.

Comment: Please file an issue with a reproducible test case in the CN1JSON issue tracker.  The example provided in this SO question works fine in the latest version of CN1JSON.